# Get Currently Active User in Android

Tags: android, android-source, multi-user

I'm looking for a way to get the current active user in Android. I'm building a system app so I can use hidden methods, but specifically it has to be the current ACTIVE user, and not the user for a given process.

For instance, if you install an app using ADB the process is going to say the user id is the owner. This means that UserHandle.myUserId() will not work for what I need :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I found a method that does exactly what I need it to do. There is a static method in ActivityManager that is hidden (so you need to work some magic to have access to it) but here it is:

```
ActivityManager.getCurrentUser();
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: This is a system API. It's not available to normal apps. This should not be an accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielOchoa the question specifies that it is a system app being developed. It's the correct answer for this question. Regular applications shouldn't care about this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use ProcessBuilder to run the shell command "whoami".

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("whoami");
    Process process = pb.start();
    // finally read the process output
```

It works.